# Targeting certain screensize and useragent to view/hide certain content content

Tags: html, css, pug

I'm developing a login form and I'm having difficulties in cross browser rendering.

When I use Chrome everything is displayed as it should be and the footer on the login form is where it should be. However when I open the login form with Firefox, the footer is not where it should be e.g at the bottom of the login form.

I want to add a `<hr>` which will only be displayed when the form is opened in Firefox browser and the width of the display is **higher than 768px**. It shouldn't be displayed in other browsers like Chrome, Safari, etc.

I'm using jade/pug and bootstrap for the front end and css to apply certain rules to the form.

My code is below.

Jade/Pug:

```
hr.div_buttons_ff
.col-md-12.col-lg-12.col-xl-12.col-sm-12
footer.footer_desk
hr.div_footer 
p.no_acc_desk Don't Have an account ?
a.join_now_desk(href="#") Join now.
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (-moz-document)
{    
   .div_buttons_ff
   {
       padding: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
       border: none;
       outline: none;
       clear: both;    
   }    
}
```

I also tried with nested media query like the following:

```
    @-moz-document url-prefix()
    {
       @media screen and (min-width:768px)
       {
          .div_buttons_ff
          {
             padding: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
             border: none;
             outline: none;
             clear: both;      
         }
      }
   }
```

Also I tried nesting the `-moz-document url-prefix()` into media but again with no success.